# Active tracking TBB doesn't render tag

Tags: profiling, tracking, personalization

I'm trying to do a PoC for Profiling and Personalisation, I have added active tracking TBB to my compound CT, but it does not render any tracking tag.

I have the added relevant Category as a Tracked Category on the Tracked Categories Tab of CT. I understand it should render `<tridion:IncrementKey runat="server"...`

Any idea if I missed out anything..

Answer (score 1):

I know that a while back the out of the box activate tracking TBB did not work, for which I created a fixed version as part of some [generic TBBs](https://sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/useful_tbbs.aspx) on Tridion World. I would have expected that this had been fixed in more recent versions though (what version are you using?), however to be honest I have not done anything with P&P for years so I couldn't tell you for sure.

Comment: Pretty sure this was fixed as of 2013. Not sure about 2011 SP1, it was definitely broken on 2011 GA.

Comment: Hi Will Thanks for your comment, I am using the latest SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 and i believe the tbbs are updated/latest!

Comment: I was scared if it has something to do with PnP licensing. but not getting any clue where did it go wrong. Anyways i will keep posted on this.

Comment: I don't think there is any licensing aspect for PnP on CMS side, so that wouldn't be it